# Wired png request in my asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

There is a simple `asp.net` page with all the resource stored locally. I use `jq1.7.2` and `bootstrap` in this page.

All works fine but a wired png request.

When the page is loaded, I got this error message:

[image]

But I searched the whole project without finding any key words as transp_bg.png or api.cld.me.

With chrome debugging, I have the network request infomation as:
[image]

Where is this request from? And how could I delete it?
Page is loaded slowly as much time is wasted on requesting this `png`.

Comment: Where did you get your version of `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 too me known possibilities:

1. you have some tracking tool that is runing on the server it self.
2. That is a dynamic placeholder from some part of a framework.

But as the request takes long my gues its a trafic tracking tool.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your browser cache "I recommend you use Firefox Web Developer"
2. Check for jquery have doubled or incompatibility issues with Bootstrap "for example old version of jquery"
3. Look be not getting an image URL as may be collecting information to the browser that that error. Download it.
4. If set photographic paper of the image is strange. Put the same icon image above